# In this code snippet,why "this" is finally binded to window object instead of array b?

Tags: javascript, foreach, this

```
"use strict";
const a=[1,2,30];
const b=[4,5,60];
const c=[7,8,90];
a.forEach((function (){
  console.log(this);
}).bind(globalThis),b);
```

In this javascript code snippet,both of `bind()` and the second parameter of `forEach()` are used to bind `this`.For `bind()`,`this` will ponit to window object while for the second parameter of `forEach()` it will point to array `b`.But finally it outpts window object for 3 times.Why?Does it relate to the code execution order or the priority of this binding in these 2 method?

Comment: once bound using `.bind(globalThis)` that function cannot be bound to anything else

Comment: [Here](https://dmitripavlutin.com/gentle-explanation-of-this-in-javascript/#62tightcontextbinding) you can found an explanation that enforces the commentary of **Jaromanda X**.

Comment: @Shidersz - thanks for that, I couldn't find anything that actually documented the behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once bound, a function can not be bound again

```js
let x = function(v,t) { console.log(this.name, v, t);}
x('unbound', 'arg2');                      // outputs [window.name unbound arg2]
x.bind({name:1}, 'one', 'arg2')();                // outputs [1 one arg2]
x.bind({name:2}, 'two', 'arg2')();                // outputs [2 two arg2]
x.bind({name:3}, 'three').bind({name:4}, 'four')(); // outputs [3 three four] rather than [4 four undefined]
```

You can see, with the last function, the `three` is bound to first argument, and `four` is bound to second argument, but `this` remains as it was with the first `bind`

Perhaps studying the output of this will help

```js
const fn = function (...args) { console.log (this.This, args.join(' ')); }
const fnBound1 = fn.bind({This: 1});
const fnBound2 = fn.bind({This: 2}, '2bound1');
const fnBound3 = fn.bind({This: 3}, '3bound1', '3bound2');
const fnBound4 = fnBound1.bind({This: 4}, '4bound1');
const fnBound5 = fnBound4.bind({This: 5}, '5bound1', '5bound2');

fnBound1('1arg1', '1arg2', '1arg3');
fnBound2('2arg1', '2arg2', '2arg3');
fnBound3('3arg1', '3arg2', '3arg3');
fnBound4('4arg1', '4arg2', '4arg3');
fnBound5('5arg1', '5arg2', '5arg3');
```

Comment: Quite understand your example.But why in my code snippet `this` will first be binded to window instead of `b`?How to analyze the binding order of the codes?

Comment: the function is declared `(function() { .... }).bind(globalThis)` it's bound before `forEach` tries to call it with a new `this`

Comment: I have thought that the function doesnt include the bind method.But I still feel doubt as it seems that both bind method and  foreach bind are certained in the lexical phase.Why it is untill function call that foreach bind happen?

Comment: I have just checked MDN and found : "The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called"     This may means the `bind` method binds `this` only when the function is called instead of when the function is declared

Comment: you're misinterpreting what you read ... it binds `this` when `bind` is called, and also any further arguments are also bound, such that these bound arguments precede the the arguments when the bound function is called

Comment: I've added another snippet @Chor - perhaps you can study the code and the output to see what is happening

Answer (score -1):

To have access to `this` or `b` use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead of bind

```
a.forEach(() => {
  console.log(this,b);
})
```

```js
"use strict";


const a=[1,2,30];
const b=[4,5,60];
const c=[7,8,90];

a.forEach(() => {
  console.log(this,b);
})
```